# Convert Sql Query To linq using sum with group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am new to linq can any body please help me out to convert following query to linq.

```
   SELECT A.Name,
   Sum(C.MoneyIN) - Sum(C.MoneyOut) AS Balance
   FROM   Customers A
   JOIN   Banks B ON A.Id = B.id
   JOIN   BankTransactions C ON B.Id = C.BankID
   GROUP  BY A.Name
```

I tried to convert it into linq

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
                     join b in db.Banks on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                     join bt in db.BankTransactions on b.Id equals bt.BankId                         
                     group c by c.Name into Cust                         
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = c.Name,
                         Balance = Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyOut) 
                     };
```

Can anybody please tell me where I am wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an error? Or is it not returning the data you want?

Comment: Sql Query working fine but compiler showing error in linq query

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: The name 'c' does not exist in the current context.
The name 'bt' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
                     join b in db.Banks on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                     join bt in db.BankTransactions on b.Id equals bt.BankId                         
                     group bt by c.Name into Cust                         
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = Cust.Name,
                         Balance = Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyOut) 
                     };
```

Seems problem was that in last select you used `c.Name` but should `Cust.Name` as you already performed grouping.

**Update 1.**

And also `Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyIn)` => `Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn)`.

**Update 2.**

Also you are grouping by wrong prop. If you want to apply sum to your BankTransactions you need to group by it like:

> group **bt** by c.Name into Cust

So working example might look like:

```
public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Bank
        {
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class BankTransaction
        {
            public int BankId { get; set; }
            public int MoneyIn { get; set; }
            public int MoneyOut { get; set; }
        }
```

And query that compiles:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
            var banks = new List<Bank>();
            var bankTransactions = new List<BankTransaction>();

            var result = from c in customers
                join b in banks on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                join bt in bankTransactions on b.Id equals bt.BankId                         
                group bt by c.Name into Cust
                select new { Name = Cust.Key, Balance = Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) };
```

Comment: I am getting this error

The name 'c' does not exist in the current context. The name 'bt' does not exist in the current context –

Comment: @WaqasAhmed updated my answer. You need to pass predicate to Sum like Cust.Sum(x=> x.MoneyIn) instead of Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyIn)

Comment: Error 2 'EntityFramework.Models.Customer' does not contain a definition for 'MoneyIn'.

Getting this error

Comment: @WaqasAhmed update answer again. Only you need to change **customers** to **db.Customers**, same with bankc and bank transactions in query

Comment: Thanks alot your solution work like a charm.
Just update Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) };
To
Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x => x.MoneyOut) };

Answer (score 1):

In Sum you need to use alias of the object. See [**Sum() here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909132%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and if `MoneyIn` and `MoneyOut` is `int` you have to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535184%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Chnage this:

```
Balance = Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(bt.MoneyOut)
```

to this:

```
Balance = Cust.Sum(x=>x.bt.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x=>x.bt.MoneyOut)
```

and the `Name` of `Cust` is the **Key** of grouping:

```
select new
      {
        Name = Cust.Key,
        Balance = Cust.Sum(x => x.bt.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x => x.bt.MoneyOut) 
      };
```

Complete query:

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
                     join b in db.Banks on c.Id equals b.CustomerId
                     join bt in db.BankTransactions on b.Id equals bt.BankId                         
                     group new { bt.MoneyIn,bt.MoneyOut} by c.Name into Cust                         
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = Cust.Key,
                         Balance = Cust.Sum(x=>x.MoneyIn) - Cust.Sum(x=>x.MoneyOut) 
                     };
```